# Missing row from MariaDB result set when constants used twice - once inside derived table and once outside

Tags: mariadb

Why is only 1 row returned when 2 definitely exist?

Here is the query I am trying to run:

```
select t.term_id, t.name, t.slug, a.c, a.term_order, a.menu_order, ttparent.taxonomy from 
(
    SELECT p.term_id, count(distinct p.ID) c, p.term_order, p.menu_order
    FROM pz_fww_object_ancestors p
    WHERE p.taxonomy = 'product_cat' and p.term_id IN (1445,9561) group by term_id 
) a inner join pz_terms t
ON a.term_id = t.term_id inner join pz_term_taxonomy ttparent on ttparent.term_id = t.term_id 
and t.term_id IN (1445, 9561)
;
```

There should be 2 rows returned, but only 1 row is returned - the one for 1445.

[image]

However - this row DEFINITELY should be returnable. If I change the final line of the query to `term_id in (9561)` then it does return the other row.

[image]

One workaround I can do is to remove this extra check of these constants against the term_id, but I'm aware that [the MySQL optimizer will not infer or pass through constants from derived tables](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=5275) and so there could be potential in some cases for the optimizer to run this query slowly if I don't also have these constants at the top level of the query rather than just on the derived table.

Here's the 2 result set with the constants removed from the outer/top-level query:

[image]

I've looked at the EXPLAIN and yes, the queries run in a different order when this additional constant check exists at the top level, so I presume this is where the bug exists.

[image]

Here's the explain from the working query, without the constants added to the top level query:

[image]

In case it matters, this is all with MariaDB version 10.3.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1.

Comment: You could remove the condition on `t.term_id in (...)` in the outer query. The condition is implicit because only the ones you want are included in the subquery result, and then those join to `t` using the `term_id` as the joining column.

Comment: I know I could do that - I DO that in the list above so you can see it working - BUT if you look at the explain, more rows are examined, thus it's slower, so I want to have the constants in both places where they should be useful. This is a bug of some kind I'm sure.

Comment: Also - I'm not sure I agree with your edit - this may or may not be specific to MariaDB.

Comment: Have you tested it on MySQL? My point is that we should not assume MariaDB is compatible with MySQL anymore. They forked in 2010, and they have both been evolving since then. There are now many incompatible behaviors. If you test on MySQL and observe the same behavior, then feel free to reapply the mysql tag.

Comment: No - have not - I'll get my client to upgrade their MariaDB version and maybe it'll be fixed there. It's a very odd error - clearly a bug. Nothing I'm doing wrong. Tried rebuilding, repairing, optimising tables, fixing collations. It's especially odd that the missing row comes back if I don't mention any other termids

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Thanks George, the code is pasted in code format too, first thing in the question pretty much. I pasted the images as *proof* of what I am saying.